# How can I make a JOIN query with LINQ between two tables (entities) with many-to-many relationship, while there is no joining table in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I didn't explicitly defined the composite table, as EF handle it automatically, but how can query results from one table with the other's Id:
take this example:

```
public class Student
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name{get; set;}
public ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

How I can get all courses for the Student with id = 3
I made this query:

```
var studentCourses = from s in context.Students join c in context.Courses on s.Id equals ?? what?
```

Should I define the joining table?

Comment: Just use the navigation property `s.Students` (which btw should be called `Courses`).

Comment: You should use Eager Loading  `context.Students.Where(d=>d.Id==3).Include(c=>c.Courses)` , but  use correct property names. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks, I wrote this in the editor as an example to the real code

Answer (score 5):

```
// Return all courses where at least one student has a specific id.
var studentId = 3;
var courses = context.Courses.Where(x => x.Students.Any(y => y.Id == studentId));
```

Or

```
var studentId = 3;
var courses = context.Students.Where(x => x.Id == studentId).SelectMany(x => x.Courses);
```

> Should I define the joining table?

No, unless it contains anything of interest. Does it add any more information than the connection between the tables, such as `DateAdded`? In that case I would create an entity for the table. But not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use property Courses from the Student class:

```
List<Course> coursesOfStudent3;
using (var dbContext = new MySchoolDbContext())
{
    coursesOfStudent3 = dbContext.Students
        .Where(student => student.studentId == 3)
        .Single()
        .Courses
        .ToList();
}
```

You get a problem if there is no student with StudentId == 3.
Consider using SelectMany:

```
coursesOfStudent3 = dbContext.Students
    .Where(student => student.studentId == 3)
    .SelectMany(student => student.Courses)
    .ToList();
```

This alternative works if there is no student with StudentId == 3. However it only works if you can guarantee that your Where clause returns only one student, which in case of selection by ID is of course the case.